# Can we fetch a table models from MySql using Nodejs ORM2 without defining all the properties/fields?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-orm2

I would like to know if we can fetch a table model from **MySql** from Database, without defining all the properties.
I'm using Node.js [ORM2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2)

```
const orm = require('orm');
db.define('users', {
    // donot want to specify all the properties/fields
  });
```

Above `users` table has already been created in DB, so I just want to get that model and not create/specify all the properties in it.
We can do this with other ORM's like Objection.js - but can't change my current implementation.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you must define properties/fields while you are defining your Models.  There aren't any other options.